# Mysql поиск вхождения подстроки в строке

Tags: mysql

Как с помощью Mysql сделать поиск по вхождению в строке?

Вот есть пример, надо найти по полю [STR] вхождение "A":

```
 [0] [N]"TABL",[STR]"A,B,C"
 [1] [N]"CATL",[STR]"B,C"
```

Вывод:

```
 [0] [N]"TABL",[STR]"A,B,C"
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE STR LIKE '%A%'

Comment: N и STR - это названия столбцов или часть текста в поле?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не очень понятно представление таблицы, если `N` и `STR` - это столбцы таблицы, то достаточно, как указано в комментариях, воспользоваться оператором `LIKE`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  STR LIKE '%A%'
```

Если же `[0] [N]"TABL",[STR]"A,B,C"` и `[1] [N]"CATL",[STR]"B,C"` это строки по которым осуществляется поиск, то лучше воспользоваться регулярными выражениями, т.е. оператором `RLIKE`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  name RLIKE "\[STR\].*A.*$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Извини, помог человек из комментариев, раз он не пишет то напишу я.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE STR LIKE '%A%'
```

Comment: Но и твое тоже подходит +